# Merging two DataTables not identical in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I merged two DataTables together but didn't get the result that I want

```
Dim reader As DataTable = db.GetExpensesBudget("Salaries", "2017")
DataGridView1.DataSource = reader

Dim reader1 As DataTable = db.GetExpensesBudget("equipments", "2017")
reader.Merge(reader1)
DataGridView1.DataSource = reader
```

The result:

[image]

I want equipments to be under Total..
I want it to look like this: Salaries,..,Total,equipments,..,Total

[image]

Comment: The first "DataGridView1.DataSource = reader" statement is not relevant. Why not compose your own final table and insert the data rows based on reader1 and reader2? Then you have full control on the result.

Comment: @JeroenHeier you are right i composed my own table and inserted the data like you said thank you